# "Google is not defined" error on ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, jruby, jrubyonrails

I have a html and js file (maps_scripts.js) in which I have defined all the google maps function related to the mentioned html page. ***These two are working really fine.***

I've been assigned to include these files to jruby on rails project developed by someone else.

So far these are the steps I took.

1. copied maps_scripts.js file to \app\assets\javascripts
2. copied related marker images to \app\assets\images
3. added

   ```
   <%= javascript_include_tag 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=my_key&libraries=places' %> "
   ```

   to my html.erb page
4. include

   ```
   <%= javascript_include_tag 'map_scripts.js', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
   ```

   to my html.erb page

**Question**

I'm getting

```
 Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined at map_scripts.self-09044ded37604e5a1f367207911e2c79370a307b67a4be3178923d19f555011c.js:4
```

***Note*** : I have several

```
   google.maps.*
```

calls in the maps_scripts.js file. For an instance

1. google.maps.MarkerImage
2. google.maps.Size
3. google.maps.Map
   etc.

Comment: Just try to reorder codes, to define google before use.
Write all code here for more help.

Comment: I solved this by changing my step 3. Instead of putting it inside html.erb I put it in application.html.erb which is now working fine

Answer (score 1):

Either you are missing a script or order of the scripts in map_scripts.js is wrong. try changing the order.

Comment: I solved this by changing my step 3. Instead of putting it inside html.erb I put it in application.html.erb which is now working fine